# Laravel how to insert multiple chekbox with different data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload different data with different values, and I am getting with dd() result like I want, but its only stored first values

[If I checked 0, 3, 5, 10 I want to insert all data together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI6KX.png)

[This is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBQv.png)

[This is my view blade page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85eCM.png)

[I want to insert in data just like this, but it only insert first array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar5jX.png)

### Edited

I find solution of this problem, all data what I want to store needs to be in one array, so I use 4 for loops and put them in one array and then insert.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple checkbox selected, then you can loop to see different selected values

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar5jX.png    i'm getting that values('vrednost') already

Comment: You get a different values in array that looks good so you can process further as per your need

Comment: Yes you are right, but its only insert in data that first array, i'm trying everything

Answer (score 0):

ensure that name of chekbox input same not different
like that

```
<input type="checkbox" name="verdnost[]" value="0">0
<input type="checkbox" name="verdnost[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="verdnost[]" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="verdnost[]" value="3">3
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but its same i tried, its only inserting data with first value